# The Rayleigh quotient on an orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume $A$ is a real symmetrical matrix and has eigenvalues as follows:
$$\lambda_{1} \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \lambda_{i} \geq 0 \geq \lambda_{i+1} \cdots \geq \lambda_n.$$
Note that these eigenvalues are not determined in sign.

It is well-know that its Rayleigh quotient is defined as follows:
$$
R(x) = \dfrac{x^{\mathsf{T}} A x}{x^{\mathsf{T}} x},
$$
and its bound is as follows:
$$
\lambda_{n} \leq R(x) \leq \lambda_{1}
$$
and the "=" is obtained when $x$ is the corresponding eigenvector.

Now the question is, given any orthogonal basis $\lbrace v_i \rbrace_{i=1}^{n}$, how are $\lbrace R(v_i) \rbrace_{i=1}^{n}$  distributed on the interval $[\lambda_{n}, \lambda_{1}]$?